# The SMTP server requires a secure connection. - Console Application

Tags: c#, console, console-application

When im open my console app project it says:

[image]

Here is my codes:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("your mail@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:\text.txt");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("save111sender@gmail.com", "test123test.");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Please help me for this problem.

Comment: No images of code. Copy your code and the exception information into the question as text

Comment: @NineBerry I did put a link to my codes picture. it doesn't seen? or broken?

Comment: @noobcoder : Do not use an image of your code.  Edit your question and post your actual code in the question, not a picture of the code.

Comment: @delvin carnate okay

Comment: Please work through the solutions in the link I posted above, and if none of them work, please update your question explaining what you have tried.

Comment: @devlincarnate Okay thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: @janzen `&` is an [ampersand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand). `@` is simply the [at sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign)

Comment: Thanks, my mistake.@PranavHosangadi